# Read json code parameter with php

Tags: php, json, tags

I want to read this json id with php.
json code:

```
<program id="2395">foo program</program>
```

php code:

```
$jsonList = json_decode($jsonCode,true);
foreach ($jsonList as $child) {
   echo $child["program"]->id;
}
```

how do I call the id? It doesn't work like this

Comment: That is not JSON.

Comment: Your json code is actually HTML.

Comment: JSON would look like this: `{"program":{"id":2395,"value":"foo program"}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [xml](http://www.w3.org/XML/) not [json](http://www.json.org/) and you may try [simplexml](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) to parse the `xml` string:

```
$xmlString = '<program id="2395">foo program</program>';
$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlString);
echo $sxe['id']; // 2395
```

This example is made using [simplexmlelement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) (Represents an element in an XML document).